# Elements or images that everyone can use for Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I need to make portrait in photoshop, I'm interested for next, does exist anywhere pages that contains elements example hair, some elements in house or photos that everyone can use. Please if you know some page just paste link to the comment. I would really appreciate it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

An old collection, not sure if thats safe for business use, but ok for testing and prototyping. Try to translate the website into your language with google translate, to find another categories:
http://lenagold.ru/fon/clipart/v/volos.html
If you need images, that you are absolutely free to use for any purpose - try unsplash or pexels, but that needs to cut hair out with photoshop.